# JavaScript window.location is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I don't seem to be able to get the JS window.location to work in my asp.net website.

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Redirect(URL) {
            window.location.href = URL;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <button id="test" title="test" onclick="Redirect('http://www.google.com');">click me</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The button seems to do a postback instead.
Is my syntax wrong? I have tried window.location without href and same result.

Comment: Have you try to open the developer tools and look if there is any error when you click on the button ?

Comment: Your button performs a postback because you have told it to do so. Use `<button type="button">` to inhibit this behavior.

Comment: That's it. It's been so long since I've used standard html buttons that I've forgotten the syntax. Thanks

Comment: you can read more here on "type" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button it is explained that the default behavior in a form is submit if non type is specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try html input

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="test" onclick="Redirect('http://www.google.com');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your javascript code with below code

```
function Redirect(URL) {
    window.location.href = URL;
    return false;
}
```

And add return when you call your javascript function i.e.

```
<button id="test" title="test" onclick="return Redirect('http://www.google.com');">click me</button>
```

In your code it was getting PostBack when you didn't return false.

Just to add if you add

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Redirect('http://www.google.com');" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please return false from onclick event to prevent page from postback

```
<button id="test" title="test" onclick="Redirect('http://www.google.com'); return false;">click me</button>
```